# Why is this error showing up?

Tags: java, jframe, rectangles

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class RectangleComponent {
public static void  paintComponent(Graphics g){
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(10,15,20,30);
    g2.draw(box);
    box.translate(30,50);
    g2.draw(box);

}
 }
```

This one is working perfectly fine. It's when I try to add it to the other code that I'm having problems. where it says: frame.add(component); I don't know why this error shows up since in the book it's exactly as I copied it. (The book is Big Java by Cay H.)    I'm using NetBeans by the way.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class Rectangleviewer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             JFrame frame = new JFrame();
             frame.setSize(300,400);
             frame.setTitle("My second frame");
             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             RectangleComponent component = new RectangleComponent();
             frame.add(component);

             frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

For the record I just want to clarify that this is not MINE it is from a book that I'm learning from and in the instructions it told me to copy it so I would see how figures show in JFrames. I can't continue reading an learning  playing with it because the next lessons involve the add.frame();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `extends JComponent` after `public class RectangleComponent`. Also remove `static` in front of `void paintComponent`.

```
public class RectangleCompoent extends JComponent {
```

and

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! It  worked :D just one question why did I have to take away the static in front of void paintComponent ?

Comment: The reason is that paintComponent is a method in JComponent. RectangleComponent extends JComponent and overrides that method. If JComponent hadn't had paintComponent in it, then RectangleComponent would not have been overriding it. In general, if class Abc has the method `public static void meth()`, then you can write `Abc.meth();` But if it had `public void meth()`, then youd have to call meth on an instance of Abc: `new Abc().meth();`

Answer (score 0):

Your RectangleComponent is merely an Object, but does not extend a Component/JComponent.